# API to Import Data in to Apache SOLR from LDAP

Tags: solr, ldap

We would like to use Apache SOLR to search users. For that we want to map the users from LDAP to SOLR. We just want to search users, we don't want any authentication as we do authentication even before it hits SOLR.
I couldn't find any API to do that. I guess I could get records from LDAP and SOLR rest API to push the data. I don't want to reinvent the wheel if there is already tool out there to help.

any help would be appreciated
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: why would you want to use Solr for searching users? LDAP is fast for searching and when you simply map your LDAP users to solr there is no additional information you can search for. so perhaps I am simply not seeing the benefit you expect from that.

Comment: Thanks for you response. We want search users from UI with AJAX. As user paused typing we want to get all the records from LDAP which  contains that text. We have tested LDAP initially, it is not near our performance requirements. We have used SOLR in the past that worked very well and SOLR especially designed for that purpose.

Comment: AFAIK thee is no direct API to access the LDAP via Solr. And even if there were it wouldn't make you happy as it would have the same speed issues as the direct approach you already tried. So I would create a script that pushes all (new and changed) users to Solr and then use Solr for the search. So no direct API but an export and import. Nevertheless I'd have a look at this speed issue as LDAP should be as fast as Solr in your use-case

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have done that, It works well. I can successfully sync data between SOLR and LDAP. Once again thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: as a Solr/elastic search user, i will have to say that there are some benefits to using a search tool versus Ldap. n-gram, suggestions/spell check, faceting come to mind.