# How to import data into Apache Solr index from LDAP

Tags: jdbc, solr, ldap, integration

I have an LDAP-Server that contains a large set of user data and would like to import this into an Apache Solr index. The question is not about whether this is a good idea or not (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23387019)). I need this kind of architecture as one of our production systems depends on a Solr index of our ldap data.

I'm considering different options to do so, but I'm not sure which one should be preferred:

**Option 1: Use the Apache Solr [DataImportHandler](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler):**

This seems to be the most straight forward Solr way of doing so. Unfortunately there does not seem to be DataSource available that would work with LDAP.

I tried to combine the JdbcDataSource with the [JDBC-LDAP-Bridge](http://myvd.sourceforge.net/bridge.html). In theory that might probably work but the driver looks quite dated (latest Version from 2007).

Another Option might be to write a custom LdapDataSource using some of the LDAP-Libraries for Java (probably [Spring LDAP](http://projects.spring.io/spring-ldap/), directly via JNDI or something similar?).

**Option 2: Build a custom Feeder:**

Another option might be to write a standalone service/script that bridges between the two services. However that feels a bit like reinventing the wheel.

**Option 3: Something I haven't thought of yet:**

Maybe there are additional options here that I simply haven't discovered yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by writing a custom LDAP DataSource for the Solr DataImportHandler.

It's not as hard as it sounds. The JdbcDataSource can be used as a template for writing your custom DataSource, so basically you just have to rewrite that one Java-Class for the LDAP protocol.

For accessing the LDAP-Client there are numerous options, such as plain JNDI, UnboundID LDAP SDK, Apache LDAP API, OpenDJ LDAP SDK or OpenLDAP JLDAP (there are probably more but I only had a look at those).

I went for UnboundID LDAP due to its well documented API and full support for LDAPv3.

Afterwards it is just a matter of referencing the datasource from the data-config.xml.

A nice side-effect of this setup is, that you can use all the goodies that the Solr DataImportHandler provides while indexing the LDAP server (Entity Processors and Transformers). This makes it easy to map the data structure between LDAP and the Solr Index.